# which csv parser can work with encoding - ISO-8859-15?

Tags: ios

which iOS CSV parser can work with encoding - ISO-8859-15 , NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding? 
it contains German characters like a , o, u with 2 dots above character.
I need to parse CSV file . Turn it to [[String]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try CHCSVParser, (ISO-8859-15 is not inclued in readme file but may be)

https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser

Comment: yes I tryed CHCSVParser. It does not work with my encoding.

Comment: my mistake,  CHCSVParser works with my encoding. I did not set delimeter so I was having wrong [[String]]. Now after I set my delimeter  all works

Comment: I also set my encoding NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding in CHCSVParser.m file